# Is dual boot the best/effective way to access a public Wi-Fi?

Tags: network, wifi

On Campus we have free Wi-Fi, specifically, [Eduroam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) which needs student credentials to be accessed (each student has its own credentials).

One thing that triggered me was that no certificate is provided when connected to the Wi-Fi (possible Wi-Fi impersonation).

I don't feel safe connecting my laptop in this network. So I was thinking a way to connect without exposing my OS to the network:

- Using a VM (but I don't think it's possible to connect only the VM to a Wi-Fi)
- Making a dual boot with a Linux distribution specifically to access this network (since I only need to use this WiFi in some classes)

For now dual boot seems a good idea but I'm not 100% sure.

Is there a better way ?
Is dual boot effective ?

Comment: Last I used it, Eduroam *did* present a certificate.

Comment: What threat are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @vidarlo Basically WiFi Impersonation

Comment: @TiagoMartins so MiTM? Why isn't TLS adequate protection against that? >99% of my traffic is more or less immune to MiTM-attacks, due to being TLS or similar.

Comment: Depending on your OS, it's *absolutely* possible to let only the VM access wi-fi. Heck, you could even use the VM to run a VPN client and then access the internet through the VPN. Actually setting it up, on the other hand, isn't necessarily easy.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I didn't know but someone give me the idea of using a USB network Adapter in VM so my host doesn't even need to have the Wi-Fi turned on. Works pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some quick choices:

- Get an USB network adapter and pass it to the VM. You don't need to connect the host to the AP.
- Configure the network adapter of the VM as bridge so that it independently connects to the network, and then you configure your host to some random IP which is not provided by the AP's network.

Comment: I tried the USB network on my VM and works well! I disabled the VM network adapter that connects to my host too. Now my host system is on Airplane Mode and I have Wi-Fi on my VM. This is enough to "isolate" my host from the public wifi ?

Comment: @TiagoMartins yes, as you said, your host is not even connected to the public wifi, so from all that matters, it's isolated.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't feel safe connecting my laptop in this network. So I was
> thinking a way to connect without exposing my OS to the network:

That's where the **firewall** comes into play: even if you have running services and therefore open ports on your computer, the firewall can prevent any of those ports being exposed on the local wifi network if you classify the "zone" as untrusted.

A third option is to use a **live OS** on a USB stick, so you don't have to partition your disk or make any changes to your computer configuration.

The question is, what are you going to use the wifi for? If you don't trust it, then you should not be using it for the purpose of sending any confidential information, even when using an ephemeral/disposable operating system (eg Tails).

However, it does makes sense to use a **VPN** that you trust (can be your own) whenever you need to connect to a third-party network you don't control and don't trust. Obviously, the VPN should identify itself with a certificate so that a rogue network can't do a MITM.

Comment: I'm not using that Wi-Fi even to go to social media or personal email, I use it only to do some class work. But my system is always checking for updates or uploading new files into cloud, in background, using that untrusted Wi-Fi. Thanks for the tip about live OS on a USB stick though!